# Linq operate with aggregate function

Tags: linq

I need to get a calculation on aggregation from linq which I hope someone can help

I have a list of objects that have 3 fields (date, saleprice and productcode) I need to get FOR EACH date (Group by date), the SUM of saleprice 
/ COUNT of distinct product code.

I know how I can find the SUM alone but not calculation by another aggregate

Comment: Show your current code, without the division.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer your question with some sample code and objects. I'll assume, `items` is your list of objects:

```
items.GroupBy(obj => obj.Date)
     .Select(g => new 
     { 
         Date = g.Key.Date, 
         Aggregate = g.Sum(obj => obj.SalePrice) / g.Select(obj => obj.ProductCode)
                                                    .Distinct().Count()
     });
```